# Decrease Vs Reduce

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Imagine a psychologist prescribes a drug to a patient, but wants to let them know about the drug's side effects; I was wondering if someone could let me kno which one of the following verbs can be used in my self-made sentences:

> - This medicine ........ sexual desire.
>
> a) [decreases](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/decrease)
>
> b) [reduces](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/reduce)

They have lots of overlaps. But I need to know which one is more preferred in this specific self-made example of mine.

Comment: Both are acceptable, and as far as I can see, equally good. I cannot think of any reason to favour one more than the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your context both "reduce" and "decrease" can be used

> This medicine *reduces* sexual desire.
>   This medicine *decreases* sexual desire.

and would have the same meaning of diminished sexual desire.

A key difference between "reduce" and "decrease" is how *something* becomes less.

One might say

> Ever decreasing steps

to mean each step is smaller than the previous step or fewer steps are used over time, but

> Ever reducing steps

would be awkward.

Answer (score 0):

I would use reduces, because it is an active verb rather than a passive one.

You could say that sexual desire decreased after the medicine was used, but decrease denotes a condition change rather than an action.